# Removing the ans in the output

Tags: string, matlab

**my m-file:**

```
function pay = salary

h = input('Please enter the number of hours worked : ');

w = input ('Please enter the hourly wage : $ ');

pay = h*w;

%this will add 50%of the hourly wage if it exceeds 40 hours

if h>40

pay = pay+((h-40)*0.5*w);

end

fprintf('The worker''s pay is $ %5.2f ', pay)
```

**output:**

> > salary
> >
> > Please enter the number of hours worked : 2
> >
> > Please enter the hourly wage : $ 2
> >
> > The worker's pay is $  4.00
> >
> > ans =
> >
> > ```
> > 4
> > ```

i want to remove the
ans = 4..
how will I do that?
can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Put a semi-colon at end `;` while calling

```
>>salary;
        ^^ semi-colon here
```

When placed at the end of a command, the semicolon tells MATLAB not to display any output from that command.